# Upgrading existing applications manually MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

I have followed the the instructions from [Upgrading existing application manually](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/dev/t_upgrading_existing_ios_native.html)

Its says :

> If you are using the latest interim fix for IBM MobileFirst Platform
> Foundation, link the IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation.framework and
> "openssl.framework" files

My question is :

1. I cant find openssl.framework in Xcode 7.1.  How to get this? (Does it obtain from this [link](http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-inclusion-of-openssl-into-iphone-app-projects/)?)
2. Why Worklight 7.1 need this?

   Our Worklight version is : 7.1.0.00-20151107-1647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure those instructions are correct; see the instructions in the following tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/configuring-a-native-ios-application-with-the-mfp-sdk/#addingNativeSDK

1. openssl.framework is not mentioned
2. I would change from manually setting it up to the new approach of using CocoaPods; going forward that is the only way to add the MFP framework.

Comment: Thank you Idan, should I add openssl.framework in my mobilefirst7.1 project?  In my mobilefirst 7.1 I only have IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.framework & SQLCipher.framework

Answer (score 0):

It is inside the Framework folder. When i created the projects, the following files are added to Framework folder:
`IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.framework
IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationJSONStore.framework
openssl.framework
SQLCipher.framework`

You might need to manually drag and drop those files.

Comment: Another advise, if you try to upgrade your old project, you may need to do the following steps as well:- Delete work light library and add work light framework.
- Add the following to the build settings of your project . ```CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
- Modified the following files with reference to work light header files.  #import <IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.h>
- Add Swift Import Path -> $(SRCROOT)/Frameworks/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.framework make it recursive.```

Comment: Thank you Siva, In my mobilefirst 7.1 I only have IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.framework & SQLCipher.framework .  I cant find openssl.framework.